# Is SU the appropriate stack for non-scripting Maya questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

It appears there have been one or two failed attempts to make a stack for users of 3D/animation/VFX software (aka technical artists). And I've identified existing stacks where Maya questions are not welcome. In the meantime, is Superuser the appropriate stack for questions about using Maya?

(but not scripting/MEL/PyMEL which is obviously Stack Overflow).

Comment: Why not [gamedev.se]?

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked at [Meta Super User](http://meta.superuser.com)?

Comment: @Won't interesting suggestion :)

Comment: @AlE. good idea, I was wanting to check that there isn't an existing stack I've missed (consider my question "which is the appropriate stack? (my best guess is SU)")